# OKD 4.5 single node installation

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, okd, redhat-containers

I'm trying to build an OKD 4.5 single node cluster following Craig Robinson blog post (at https://medium.com/swlh/guide-okd-4-5-single-node-cluster-832693cb752b). I faced with this issue first on bootstrap node, but after deleting and recreating the whole process again, it booted up successfully. But the same issue happened again while preparing control plane master node. After initial coreos download (which proves webserver is working fine), I get this recurring GET error message over and over again:

```
ignition[xxx]: GET error: Get "https://api-int.lab.okd.local:22623/config/master": EOF
```

And this is my control plane node config:

```
ip=10.106.31.233::10.106.31.1:255.255.255.0:::none nameserver=10.106.31.231 coreos.inst.install_dev=/dev/sda coreos.inst.image_url=http://10.106.31.231:8080/okd4/ fcos.raw.xz coreos.inst.ignition_url=http://10.106.31.231:8080/okd4/master.ign
```

IPs are:
okd-services: 10.106.31.231 ;
bootstrap: 10.106.31.232 ;
control-plane: 10.106.31.233

I can reach the http://10.106.31.231:8080/okd4 address from remote pc and list the contents including master.ign file. Also pinging "api-int.lab.okd.local" is successful too. firewalld open ports on okd-services node are:

```
[root@okd4-services ~]# ss -ltu
Netid            State              Recv-Q             Send-Q                         Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port            Process
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                                    0.0.0.0:hostmon                                   0.0.0.0:*
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                              10.106.31.231:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                                  127.0.0.1:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                              127.0.0.53%lo:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                                       [::]:hostmon                                      [::]:*
udp              UNCONN             0                  0                                       [::]:domain                                       [::]:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  128                                  0.0.0.0:ssh                                       0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                               127.0.0.1:rndc                                      0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:https                                     0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:22623                                     0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:cslistener                                0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:sun-sr-https                              0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:hostmon                                   0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                 0.0.0.0:http                                      0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  10                             10.106.31.231:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  10                                 127.0.0.1:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                           127.0.0.53%lo:domain                                    0.0.0.0:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  128                                     [::]:ssh                                          [::]:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                   [::1]:rndc                                         [::]:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  4096                                    [::]:hostmon                                      [::]:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  511                                        *:webcache                                        *:*
tcp              LISTEN             0                  10                                      [::]:domain                                       [::]:*
```

the output of the dig test on okd-services node is:

```
[root@okd4-services ~]# dig -x 10.106.31.231

; <<>> DiG 9.11.25-RedHat-9.11.25-2.fc33 <<>> -x 10.106.31.231
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60620
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;231.31.106.10.in-addr.arpa.    IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
231.31.106.10.in-addr.arpa. 604800 IN   PTR     api-int.lab.okd.local.
231.31.106.10.in-addr.arpa. 604800 IN   PTR     api.lab.okd.local.
231.31.106.10.in-addr.arpa. 604800 IN   PTR     okd4-services.okd.local.

;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
```

I deleted and recreated the control plane to see if it solved the issue, but was not successful. Any idea what this issue means?

Answer (score 1):

I had exact the same issue with this article. The problem was with bootstrap node that cannot finish initialization process. First of all initialize bootstrap node and sure that the process was finished. The simplest way to check what's going on with a node:

1. Connect to a node with `ssh core@<NODE'S-IP>` from the machine where you generate ssh-certificate
2. ssh will provide you useful information:

> This is the bootstrap node; it will be destroyed when the master is
> fully up.
>
> The primary services are release-image.service followed by
> bootkube.service. To watch their status, run e.g.
>
> journalctl -b -f -u release-image.service -u bootkube.service This
> is the bootstrap node; it will be destroyed when the master is fully
> up.
>
> The primary services are release-image.service followed by
> bootkube.service. To watch their status, run e.g.
>
> journalctl -b -f -u release-image.service -u bootkube.service Fedora
> CoreOS 32.20200629.3.0 Tracker:
> https://github.com/coreos/fedora-coreos-tracker Discuss:
> https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/c/server/coreos/

3. First of all you have to check `journalctl -b -f -u release-image.service -u bootkube.service` because it's main units. However, there're might be other issues so check failed/not finished systemd's service units with `systemctl list-units --type=service` and `journalctl -f -u <UNIT-NAME>` to follow the process
4. Whole process will spend some time (~20-40 mins in my case) and there're might be some timeouts in journal's logs so just wait the final status of the unit.
5. Only then you can start initializing of control-plane node

Finally, my issue was in wrong fedora-core-os version because you can use 32 version only. For me it's installed okay with:

- [fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz](https://builds.coreos.fedoraproject.org/prod/streams/stable/builds/32.20201104.3.0/x86_64/fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz)
- [fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz.sig](https://builds.coreos.fedoraproject.org/prod/streams/stable/builds/32.20201104.3.0/x86_64/fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-metal.x86_64.raw.xz.sig)
- [fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-live.x86_64.iso](https://builds.coreos.fedoraproject.org/prod/streams/stable/builds/32.20201104.3.0/x86_64/fedora-coreos-32.20201104.3.0-live.x86_64.iso)
- [openshift-client-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz](https://github.com/openshift/okd/releases/download/4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428/openshift-client-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz)
- [openshift-install-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz](https://github.com/openshift/okd/releases/download/4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428/openshift-install-linux-4.5.0-0.okd-2020-10-15-235428.tar.gz)